# How to setup HUD widgets correctly in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

I am following a tutorial on Udemy on Unreal Engine based game development. I have posted the sam question on Udemy as well. I will try my best to explain the issue I am facing.

#### What works

I have set up a

- GameMode named `FPS_GameMode`,
- GameInstance named `FPS_GameInstance`,
- HUD named `FPS_HUD`

I have set the HUD in `FPS_GameMode` to `FPS_HUD`.
I have assigned the `FPS_GameMode` as GameMode in project settings.

Now I have created 2 blueprints `MainHUD` and `UI_DynamicCrosshair`. `UI_DynamicCrosshair` consists of functionality related to resizing the crosshair if the character is moving. (It spreads out if the character is moving).
I have used this crosshair in the `MainHUD` (used `UI_DynamicCrosshair` in the `MainHUD`'s viewport).
In my `FPS_Character` blueprint, I am creating the `MainHUD` widget and adding it to the viewport.

The crosshair widget shows up when I play the game but it does not update when my character moves.

#### What doesn't work

I need to call the functionality defined in my `UI_DynamicCrosshair`, in `FPS_Character` so that I can trigger it when the character moves.
For that, I tried using the `MainHUD` reference as it is accessible in the `FPS_Character` blueprint assuming that I would be able to access the `UI_DynamicCrosshair` via the `MainHUD` reference. But this doesn't work. The `UI_DynamicCrosshair` is not accessible via the `MainHUD` reference.

Can you share a checklist/list-of-steps so that I can crosscheck everything I have done and figure out what I have missed?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming it's all in Blueprints, because you're not mentioning any C++ code.

Seems to me that your `UI_DynamicCrosshair` instance is just set as **private**, as you would normally be able to access it via a `MainHUD` reference if it were set as **public**.
Make sure that [this checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlpVF.jpg) is **unchecked** in your `MainHUD` class, when your `UI_DynamicCrosshair` variable is selected.

Although, the better (or nicer) way to achieve this would be to create a **public function**, let's say `SetCharacterMovement(Boolean bIsMoving)`, in your `MainHUD`, and to implement the logic that does the resizing in it.

You can then just **call this function** on your `MainHUD` reference from your `FPS_Character` when you need to update the crosshair. That way your PlayerCharacter does not have to be aware of the inner logic of your HUD, which takes care of itself (and its 'children').

It's a principle called [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), and that will help you design things the clean way.